# Filling in blank dictionary values based on other key value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, missing-data

I have a df that contains a column ['mjtheme_namecode'] which is in dictionary form  containing a code and a name.  The codes all have numbers but some of the names are missing.  I would like to fill in the missing name values based on other pairs with the same code.  Here is the df column in question:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = pd.read_json('data/world_bank_projects.json')
print(df['mjtheme_namecode'].head(15))

0     [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, {...
1     [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},...
2     [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'...
3     [{'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/incl...
4     [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'...
5     [{'code': '6', 'name': 'Social protection and ...
6     [{'code': '2', 'name': 'Public sector governan...
7     [{'code': '11', 'name': 'Environment and natur...
8     [{'code': '10', 'name': 'Rural development'}, ...
9     [{'code': '2', 'name': 'Public sector governan...
10    [{'code': '10', 'name': 'Rural development'}, ...
11    [{'code': '10', 'name': 'Rural development'}, ...
12                          [{'code': '4', 'name': ''}]
13    [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'...
14    [{'code': '6', 'name': 'Social protection and ...
Name: mjtheme_namecode, dtype: object
```

I know I could make the column a separate df and then ffill, but I think I would have to reindex, so I don't think I could put it back in place after that. I'm thinking ideally I'd make a list (with no duplicates) of only dict items with both codes and names then use that list to iterate over the dictionary in a for loop where name becomes the matching value from the non-duplicate list I created.  Does this make sense?  Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @Zonk can you show a few rows where the code is empty?

Comment: https://github.com/jl3392/Data-Wrangling-practice/blob/master/Json%20exercise%20practice.ipynb

Comment: Code is never empty just name, index 12 above for example

Comment: Ah, it's the *name* that's empty, got it.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all rows with the same value for code have either `None` for `name`, lack the key `name` altogether or have the same value for `name`?

Comment: If I'm understanding tobsecret correctly, for each unique code, they either have the same name or no name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a similar approach of creating a new DataFrame, but then transition back:

```
theme= pd.DataFrame([val for pair in df['mjtheme_namecode'].values for val in pair])
mapper = theme.drop_duplicates().replace(r'', np.nan).dropna().set_index('code').name.to_dict()
```

Using a list comprehension to put it all together:

```
s = pd.Series(
    [[{'code': i['code'], 'name': mapper[i['code']]}
        for i in t] for t in df.mjtheme_namecode]
)

s.head(13)

0     [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, {...
1     [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},...
2     [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'...
3     [{'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/incl...
4     [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'...
5     [{'code': '6', 'name': 'Social protection and ...
6     [{'code': '2', 'name': 'Public sector governan...
7     [{'code': '11', 'name': 'Environment and natur...
8     [{'code': '10', 'name': 'Rural development'}, ...
9     [{'code': '2', 'name': 'Public sector governan...
10    [{'code': '10', 'name': 'Rural development'}, ...
11    [{'code': '10', 'name': 'Rural development'}, ...
12    [{'code': '4', 'name': 'Financial and private ...
dtype: object
```

As you can see, the last row (row 12) has been correctly filled in, as have the others, and you can reassign this to your original DataFrame.

Comment: how would I reassign?

Comment: @Zonk if this answered your question, please consider voting on and accepting this answer!